# Is it okay to raise to the power of $n$ (where $n\in\mathbb{R}$) on both sides in Euler's Identity?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

So I was playing around with the identity and did this:
$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
$$e^{(2\pi)i}=(-1)^{2}=1$$
$$e^{(2n\pi)i}=1^{n}=1\ \ \ \ \ (n\in \mathbb{R})$$
$$\Rightarrow\ e^{(2n\pi)i}=e^{(2\pi)i}\ \ (\forall n\in\mathbb{R})$$

Then, $$2n=2$$ So,$$n=1$$

Which is quite contradicting as any value of n should satisfy the condition. Which means I have made a mistake somewhere. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong? Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't conclude $2n=2$ from $e^{(2n\pi) i}=e^{(2\pi)i}$; e.g., $\cos(10\pi)=\cos(0),$ but $10\pi\ne0$

Comment: For starters, $n$ needs to be an integer (e.g. suppose $n = 1/2$ in your third line and you'll see a contradiction). As for the remaining question, you noticed that $e^{2n \pi i} = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$. There is no contradiction as you are just multiplying by 1 in a different way.

Comment: This is no different to saying $1^1 = 1^2$, therefore $1=2$

Comment: Thank you all, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1^m =1^n $$ does not imply $$m=n$$

The positive  real number base $b$ should be different from 1  to have $$b^m=b^n $$implies $$m=n$$

Answer (score 0):

No.  But the ever useful *De Moivre's formula* falls out by doing $e^{ni\theta}=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$.